# .htaccess redirect all to domain from subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all request from my domain subfolder to another domain but don't preserve folder or querystring. (.htacess has to be in that subfolder folder/folder2)

like this:

```
 http://example.com/folder/folder2/?query=test
 ->
 http://newexample.com/
```

all my attempts ending with redirect like this:

```
 http://newexample.comfolder/folder2/?query=test
```

I did try this: (and more all with same result)

```
Redirect 301 / http://newexample.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newexample.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^.+$ http://newexample.com/ [R=302,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just this rule in root .htaccess of old domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newexample.com/? [R=302,L]
```

`?` at the end of target URL will strip off any previous query string.

Comment: This is not working folders are preserved.
I get ```http://newexample.comfolder/folder2```

//Sorry my bad. It's working